# Django and Pillow

Tags: python, django, macos, python-imaging-library

In my Django project, I try to run server with:

```
python manage.py runserver 9000
```

But I have this error:

> ERRORS:
>
> api.NameOfProject.profile_picture: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed. HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow or run command "pip install pillow".
>
> api.Photo.photo: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed. HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow or run command "pip install pillow".

I install Pillow on my Mac OSX system with:

```
pip install pillow
```

But it's the same...
And I also tried to install with Homebrew...

Comment: And pillow shows up if you `pip freeze`?

Comment: Yes. It's in my requirements.txt file. Pillow==2.7.0

Comment: Did you install its dependencies? Check the [installation steps](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/installation.html#mac-os-x-installation)

Comment: @argaen Yes.

brew install libtiff libjpeg webp little-cms2
Warning: libtiff-4.0.3 already installed
Warning: jpeg-8d already installed
Warning: webp-0.4.2_1 already installed
Warning: little-cms2-2.6 already installed

Comment: Start the Django shell and check if you could import the pillow library. This seems like some error with the Python path/ pip. You might be using a different Python interpreter for the pip and your Python

Comment: Are you using python virtual environment? Do you see Pillow in your `site-packages` directory? e.g. in my virtual env it is in `~/Envs/venvname/lib/python2.7/site-packages`  where I have the different packages installed.

Comment: Yes my problem was between my Python interpreter for the pip and my Python...
I download source code and installed Pillow with: `sudo python setup.py install`. Now it's okay. I don't really understand where was issue with homebrew... Thanks guys.

Comment: It sounds like you have two versions or instances of python installed...

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem, and my solution was much simpler:

**Apparently packages PIL and Pillow can't coexist. If you want to use Pillow you first have to uninstall PIL and then install Pillow**.

If you are on Mac, you have to install a few libraries as well using brew. Mentioned below is the sequence of steps:

```
$pip uninstall PIL
$brew install libtiff libjpeg webp little-cms2
$pip install Pillow
```

To test if pillow is installed and ready to use, open python interpreter and try to import the following:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
```

*note that the library still says PIL but now it is importing from Pillow instead of PIL.

If you are able to successfully import then you are good to go (in all probability you won't have to worry about setting PYTHONPATH or 32/64-bit installations)

Source: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/installation.html

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue.

I download source code here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow and installed Pillow with: `sudo python setup.py install`

If someone can explain to me what was the problem with homebrew.